# Round to leading digit in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

Can I define a *round* function in gnuplot that automatically rounds numbers not to a close integer (like floor etc.) but to the leading digit, like

```
round(0.00230354) = 0.002 ?
```

Of course, I could multiply every value by the correct power of 10 and then *floor* it. But in order to do so I would need to look at every number individually.
I would want to use the function to label color bars where I determine the tics positions dynamically with the *stats* command for varying datasets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could most likely use `sprintf` for this task (i.e., to obtain first the "rounded" string representation of the number of interest which is then converted back to a number via the `real` function):

```
gnuplot> x = real(sprintf("%.0E", 0.00230354));print x
0.002
gnuplot> x = real(sprintf("%.0E", 0.00260354));print x
0.003
```

So in terms of a custom function `round`, the example would look like:

```
gnuplot> round(x) = real(sprintf("%.0E", x));
gnuplot> print round(0.00230354);
0.002
```

Or if you wanted just the string representation which you could then use directly for the labels then perhaps the `g/G` conversion specifier might be more relevant:

```
gnuplot> s = sprintf("%.1g", 0.00230354); print s
0.002
gnuplot> s = sprintf("%.1g", 0.000000230354); print s
2e-07
gnuplot> s = sprintf("%.1g", 0.000000260354); print s
3e-07
```